# Aggregation using elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have my search query for fetch latest 5000 documents from my elastic DB as below

```
{ 
  "size": 5000, 
  "from": 0, 
  "query": {
        "range" : {
            "hostTimestamp" : {
                "gte" : 1499674634382,
                "lte" : 1499680034000
            }
        }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "hostTimestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now in the documents that are fetched as result of this query I want to count no of documents with `eventSeverity` as `Alert` or `Critical`. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on the `eventSeverity` field:

```
{ 
  "size": 5000, 
  "from": 0, 
  "query": {
        "range" : {
            "hostTimestamp" : {
                "gte" : 1499674634382,
                "lte" : 1499680034000
            }
        }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "hostTimestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {                  <--- add this part
    "severities": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "eventSeverity"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This gives me aggregate count but it gives me aggregation for all the records in the time range defined in the query. But I need severity count for the top 5000 events only and not all the events in the defined range. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: You can get the Top 5000 via the Top Hits aggregation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) and inside this aggregation you can use the aggregation above.

Comment: @MartinSchulze you cannot define sub-aggregations inside the `top_hits` one.